# System of two linear differential equations, third order

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the simplest way to solve this system of equations?

$x'''(t) = 2 x(t) + y(t)$

$y'''(t) = x(t) + 2 y(t)$

Initial values $x(0) = 0$, $x'(0) = 0$, $x''(0)=1$, $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = 0$ and $y''(0) = 1$ are known.

Comment: A typo, yes it is.

Comment: I was going to answer this but since on reflection it is most likely homework, I will simply leave a comment: you need six linearly independent solutions.  What would you do for a single equation of this form?

Comment: @Julienne: What are you currently studying as there are several approaches to solve these?

Comment: So there is no faster way than writing down a 6x6 matrix ...?

Comment: Solving simple linear sistems with matrices.

Comment: Since you have not accepted or upvoted to the answers, do you need more help?

Comment: Thank you, your approach is gold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the first equation from the second and set $z(t)=y(t)-x(t)$. Then you will have a 3rd order equation in $z$: $$z'''-z=0$$
with the characteristic eqution $r^3-1=0$. Also initial conditions ($z(0)=z'(0)=z''(0)=0$) imply that $z(t)=0$, so $x(t)=y(t)$ (This is due to the uniqueness of solutions of the IVP and zero initial conditions). Therefore, it is enough to solve $y'''=3y$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laplace transform techniques. Also, you can apply this [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450159/differential-equation-by-systematic-elimination/450834#450834).

Comment: I think it would be good to be a little more precise, and give the OP a little more guidance.